# Export missing string in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to maintain an app translated into more than 10 different languages. Whenever a new version is developed, new strings are added to the source values.xml . The translation editor helps me to get an overview about which strings are missing in other languages, but at the moment, it looks like there is no option to get a diff xml with just the new strings added for each language. Since we use translation services we have to pay per translated word. Therefore I always have to manually create the files with the missing translations, which is very time consuming.

I can't imagine I'm the only one needing this particular feature. Is there a workaround / script / plugin which does solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Back in the steam age I faced similar problem while trying to keep like 14 translations in sync, so I created small PHP script to to help me with this.

As I said it's pretty dated (2010 :) yet it should work. I just made it available on GitHub: https://github.com/MarcinOrlowski/android-strings-check

Basically what it does is diff two translation XMLs and generate human readable report:

```
./strings-check.php values/strings.xml values-pl/strings.xml
```

It will give you the output like this:

```
Missing in LANG (You need to add these)
File: values-pl/strings.xml
------------------------------------------------------
show_full_header_action
hide_full_header_action
recreating_account

Not present in BASE (remove it from your LANG file)
File: values/strings.xml
------------------------------------------------------------------
provider_note_yahoo

Summary
----------------
BASE file: 'values/strings.xml'
LANG file: 'values-pl/strings.xml'
   3 missing strings
   1 orphaned strings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but this just shows me where I'm missing something, right? It does not generate a diff of the xml values files?

Comment: No, it will just show you what is missing or redundant. I created this script for me only - just sharing it now. Yet, it generates diff internally so it can be updated to also write diff XMLs instead of just showing the report. The additional trick here is that if your translation lacks given key, then framework will fallback to default values but if you add the key but no translation, then you will end up with empty string in your app. Also manual update allows checking if all is fine. So I'd personally rather hand my translator original strings.xml and the report.

Comment: Ok, but reporting missing translations is already part of lint nowadays. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Script is dated like 2010, so many things changed Still, if you need custom functionality you can consider this as foundation. Whatever :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I guess I found the solution to my problem, a python script called android-localization-helper:

https://github.com/jordanjoz1/android-localization-helper